# Constant flash player problems

Tags: google-chrome, flash

While running google chrome stable i get the error

```
6629:6629:0905/161937:ERROR:chrome_content_client.cc(335)] Failed to locate and load the component updated flash plugin.
```

This occurs immediately after the command is entered, then the browser starts but then I cannot view some news videos. Google chrome reinstall no help..? What to do

Answer (score 4):

This is a shot in the dark based on a similar problem reported in February 2013. First if Chrome is running close it. Then open the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
chmod -R 0700 ~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash
rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash
```

This will cause the working copy of Flash configuration to be deleted and the next time you start Chrome it is rebuilt from defaults. Type `exit` to close the Terminal.

The other option is to purge and reinstall Chrome which it sounds like you've already done.

When I ran the commands on my Ubuntu 16.04 version the PepperFlash file was removed as expected. However when I started a TV show that uses flash the file wasn't recreated but yet the TV show worked normally. The Pepperflash file must have been leftover from an older version of Chrome which is no longer needed in Chrome version 53.0.2785.92 (64-bit) that I'm using.

Hopefully it works for you but as I prefaced, "it's a shot in the dark".

Comment: My problem was I was using same installation across different linux installation and my other install's home urls was different. Fixing the url in the text file in ~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash fixed the problem.