# Problems after upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10 from 18.04

Tags: upgrade, gnome-shell, gtk, 19.10, ubuntu-dock

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10 from 18.04 (after going through 19.04) and I have a few problems.

1) The dock with icons is not showing up. I tried the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183098/dock-disappeared-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-19-10-only-visible-in-activities-overv), but it didn't work for me.

2) When I press the Activities button, I am not sure what is supposed to happen (I never used it in 18.04), but both my screens go darker (I have a second monitor) and a search bar appears on the main, from which I can search for software I have installed and I can launch it. However I can't seem to 'exit' this Activities thing. Whatever and whereever I click it stays on and in particular I can't click on anything that I have launched through it (the Activities things is transparent, so I can see the programs I am launching). The only way I have found of 'closing' it is by doing Alt+F2 and 'r', but I assume this is not its intended usage.

3) In Settings, if I go to the 'Devices' section, then whenever I switch between more than 2 of the subsections (Keyboard, Mouse, etc.) the window starts flickering and I can't click on it anymore. I can close it with Alt+F4. This applies to the `gnome-tweaks` as well. The error I get in terminal is

```
(gnome-tweaks:10198): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:08:37.757: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width -23 and height 19
```

It is apparently a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-tweaks/+bug/1847524) affecting multiple users that hasn't been resolved yet.

4) There is some kind of a diagonal line on my second (physical) screen, but primary as defined in the settings, that is not visible unless scrolling through a page with text, because it distorts the text as the text passes by it - similar to light going through the interface of two media with different refractive index. My second screen worked great until before the update, so I doubt it is a hardware problem with it

5) Vivaldi doesn't launch. Here is the error I get in terminal

```
(vivaldi:7580): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:35:37.764: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2:0: Expected a valid selector
[7580:7580:1202/103537.825606:ERROR:chrome_content_client.cc(343)] Failed to locate and load the component updated flash plugin.
[7610:7610:1202/103537.895850:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(369)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[7580:7719:1202/103537.967988:ERROR:database.cc(1581)] Calendar sqlite error 1, errno 0: no such column: etag, sql: update events set etag = ''
[7580:7719:1202/103537.968014:ERROR:calendar_database.cc(47)] Calendar DB failed to migrate from version 1. Calendar API will be disabled.
[7580:7719:1202/103537.972650:ERROR:calendar_backend.cc(152)] INIT_TOO_NEW
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried the proposed solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/821397/constant-flash-player-problems), but it didn't help.

**UPDATE:** 2) was apparently caused by an extension called Workspace grid, which doesn't work with 19.10, so I removed it (and replaced it with Workspace matrix). That problem, 2), is now fixed

**UPDATE 2:** 4) was resolved (at least I can't see the line where I previously could) by reininstalling the NVIDIA drivers.

**UPDATE 3:** I tried disabling all my gnome extensions and then restarting - nothing changed - all the remaining (1,3,5) problems were still there.

**UPDATE 4:** 1) was resolved after what it seems to me a random sequence of events that might not all be linked to the resolution. Namely:

1-Uninstall "Dash to Dock" gnome extension after upgrading to 19.10 (it worked well in 18.04).

1.5-A large number of other operations connected with resolving other problems or just doing work on the machine. None of them seem relevant to gnome for me.

2-Reinstalled NVIDIA-440 drivers and restarted machine.

3-Installed "Dash to Dock" again. Not working.

4-Reverted back to NVIDIA-435 drivers and restarted machine.

5-Reinstalled "Dash to Dock". Working.

6-Upgraded to NVIDIA-440 drivers and restarted machine. "Dash to Dock" works and I can use the dock icons outside of "Activities".

**UPDATE 5:** A workaround for 2) is to first resize the settings window a bit with the mouse and then make it full screen through the button for doing so. This enables one to use the settings menu.

Comment: Disable all your extensions to see what problems (if any) go away.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Just tried that. Disabled everything and restarted. All the problems were still there (apart from the newly resolved 4), as just updated in the question). Btw, the dock with icons shows up when I press Activities and I can use it then, but I can't use it in any other way. Is this the intended behaviour?

Comment: I upgraded 16.04 direct to 19.04 on test partition but kept Unity interface for "no surprises"

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I decided to switch with 18.04, as it seems that the support for Unity will eventually disappear. I had no problems on 18.04, so it is very strange that on 19.10, I get so many issues.